# Find the value of $\iint_D (xy)^{\frac{2}{3}} \,dx\,dy$ where $D=\{(x,y)|1\leq x^{\frac{2}{3}}+y^{\frac{2}{3}}\leq4, x\geq 0,y\geq 0\}$

Tags: integration

> Find the value of  $\iint_D (xy)^{\frac{2}{3}} \,dx\,dy$ where $D=\{(x,y)|1\leq x^{\frac{2}{3}}+y^{\frac{2}{3}}\leq4, x\geq 0,y\geq 0\}$
>
> Use a substitution to solve the problem.

I have tried to play around with some substitutions but I either got a function that is hard to integrate (for exapmle when I tried using $x=rcos^3\theta$, $y=rcos^3\theta$) or couldn't figure the new poles of integration.

If possible I would like to see a solution that doesn't rely on a sketch.

I feel like a polar substitution is the way to go here, because I get a "circle-ish" feeling from the domain.

Please explain in your solution:

1. Why did you choose this substitution.
2. How did you find the new domain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X:=x^{1/3}$ and $Y:=y^{1/3}$ then $\left|\frac{\partial(X,Y)}{\partial(x,y)}\right|=\frac{1}{9X^2Y^2}$ and
$$\iint_D (xy)^{\frac{2}{3}} \,dx dy=\iint_{1\leq X^2+Y^2\leq 4,X\geq 0,Y\ge0} 9X^4Y^4  dXdY\\
=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{1}^2 r^9\cos^4(\theta)\sin^4(\theta) d\theta dr$$
where at the second step we used polar coordinates. For the trigonometric part see [Wallis' integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals).

Can you take it from here?

P.S. The final result should be $\frac{27621\pi}{2560}$.

Comment: I actually managed to reach this one by myself, but I was left wondering if there is a simpler way, because I can't use known integrals and have to prove everything by myself, which makes the trigonometric part pretty annoying.

Comment: Another question is, how would you go to solve $\iint_D x(xy)^{\frac{2}{3}} \,dx\,dy$ where $D$ is the same domain?

Comment: In the same way, just multiply $9X^4Y^4 $ by the extra-factor $x=X^3$. In this case the trigonometric part is easier.

Comment: I am left with some nasty (to my standards) trigonometric expression.

Comment: For the trigonometric part, use the recurrence relation explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals#Recurrence_relation

It is easy. Just integration by parts.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot.